# Would doing an independent study or directed reading help me get into grad school with a poor undergraduate record?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

My goal is to get into a math graduate program within the next 5 years. The trouble is that I have very poor undergraduate grades no research experience, and no current connections, since I graduated 7 years ago.

**Would doing an independent study / directed reading / directed study class help me overcome this?** This seems like a good way to improve my letters of recommendation and explore topics not covered in conventional courses. Or would some other avenue be better?

**If so, how could I find a professor to oversee such a course?**

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I suggest you cut the length of this question by a factor of 3. For example, your first bullets could be summarized by "I have bad grades and no research experience and am trying to figure out how to get into math grad school." You should also avoid asking multiple questions in one post -- your first two questions could maybe be combined (though this may be a duplicate), while the third and fourth questions could each be their own post.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I will work on that. I wasn't sure how several rapid-fire questions will look but I will do that.

Comment: @cag51: Just wondering your thoughts, do you think if I separate the questions they are likely to all be closed as duplicates? I do feel like I am asking some questions that aren't answered in the linked question (which I read before posting this), but I don't want to clog up the forum with closed questions.

Comment: @cag51: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: How long has it been since undergrad? A poor record 20 years ago is very different than if you just graduated.

Comment: I updated the question with that information in case it was relevant, I graduated 7 years ago, plenty of time to get my act together :)